# How to set a static html front page

Tags: frontpage

I'm trying to set a wordpress static HTML front page, which doesn't seem trivial.

I tried three approaches:

1) add a index.html, and rename index.php to blog.php. Change the permalink into custom: `/blog.php?p=%postid%`. However for handling categories, the generated link is `/blog.php?p=cat=3`.

2) add a index.html, and rename index.php to blog.php. Change the installation position into `www.mydomain.com/blog.php` in my dashboard. This time it direct to `www.mydomain.com/blog.php/?p=123`.

3) add a page and set it to be displayed as frontpage in my dashboard/settings/reading. However for this solution, I don't know how to change the overall html of a page edited in wordpress. I can only modify the html for the body but I need to change it whole.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried leaving `index.php` alone and adding `index.html`?

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily change permalinks back to the default settings.

Create a page template and name it `page_home.php`. Add this to the file:

```
<?php

// Template name: Static Front Page
```

You can add code to display the page content later. Like the contents of the index.php file.

Save the file to your theme (or child theme) directory. Create a new page, name it and select `Static Front Page` from the Template dropdown. Publish the page and select it as your front page in the Settings -> Reading page.

You can add code to the template file to affect the front page style like any other template file. `http://www.mydomain.com/` should go to your front page.

Now you can muck with permalinks settings if you wish.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to change permalinks settings to implement this setup. Creating the new page & setting it up to use your template file, and then setting WordPress to use this new page for the front page, should have no effect on permalinks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's an easier way to do this.

You only need to change the name of `index.html` into anything different (like `mylanding.php` or whatsoever).

Then you put this file into the folder of your active theme and edit it by adding this line to the very beginning:

```
<?php /* Template Name: mylanding*/?>
```

Now create a page with any random name and content or edit an existing one. The main thing here is to choose the template "mylanding" in the right column.

Go *Settings* —> *Reading* and set this page as the front one.

[How to Add a Static HTML Page to WordPress](http://www.templatemonster.com/blog/integrate-static-html-wordpress/?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=e-stackexchange&utm_campaign=blog)